# Is there an equalizer for windows that works regardles of audio/video player

Tags: windows, video, audio, music

I'm tired of having to tweak the audio on every media application I have installed.

Is there an app that will sit between any media application and my sound-card so that I can set audio levels and equalizer settings once and for all?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I just discovered the Equalizer APO project.  It takes a fair amount of work to set up, but it's infinitely more customizable than Breakaway (and it's free).

http://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/

As detailed in the docs, you can generate filters using Room EQ Wizard.

http://www.hometheatershack.com/roomeq/

Then you can of course tweak and add more filters to your heart's content.

Comment: I'll take a look! Breakaway hasn't been updated for years and I can't seem to get it to work properly with Win8 :(

Answer (score 12):

I know an answer has already been accepted but I recently discovered [Breakaway Audio Enhancer](http://www.claessonedwards.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=46&Itemid=59) which is just amazing.

> Breakaway Audio Enhancer dramatically
>   improves the quality of the listening
>   experience by digitally remastering
>   audio in real-time with the same
>   technology used by the pros in the
>   music and broadcast business. Any
>   media player playlist can sound like a
>   professionally produced CD with
>   automatic adjustment of volume
>   dynamics and spectral balancing.
>
> Breakaway Audio Enhancer incorporates
>   state-of-the-art 4, 5, 6, or 7 band
>   dynamics processor (depending on
>   selected preset) that examines and
>   adjusts the audio thousands of times a
>   second. Low levels are intelligently
>   raised and loud signals are kept under
>   control, all in real-time. Anything
>   playing in the media player or web
>   browser, including MP3s, Video,
>   Internet radio, or CDs will be
>   digitally remastered for consistent
>   volume level and spectral balance.
>   Files are not scanned or modified. All
>   the audio processing takes place in
>   real-time while the audio is sent to
>   your speakers or headphones.
>
> With Breakaway Audio Enhancer there is
>   no longer a need to purchase separate
>   audio enhancement plug-ins for each of
>   your media players. Breakaway Audio
>   Enhancer will enhance the audio for
>   all Windows audio & video players. It
>   provides audio processing for the
>   complete computer system.

[image]

Comment: +1 nice find. It's not free (but not too expensive either). I'll try the 30-day free trial.

Comment: I just installed this. It's badass. 30 day free trial, but I'm definitely going to be buying it.

Answer (score 5):

Some sound cards will install a software equalizer as a part of the driver package for that particular sound card. The Realtek audio driver automatically installs a control panel (rthdcpl.exe) with equalizer.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Free [DFX](http://www.fxsound.com/dfx/download.php), while not a true equalizer, allows for source-independent sound adjustment that probably satisfies most people. *(How many have proper speakers, the ear and will bother to adjust the equalizer per song/album?)*

[image]